# Get foreground app package name using ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses() in service

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I want to get the package name of the application running in the foreground. For that, I found that we can use this:

```
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);    
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> tasks = manager.getRunningAppProcesses(); 
Log.i("current_app", tasks.get(0).processName);
```

But when I checked [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses()), it says:

```
Note: this method is only intended for debugging or building a user-facing process management UI.
```

Why is it so? Is there any problem if we use this in production (which is to be deployed to public play store)?

Comment: "For that, I found that we can use this" -- if you read the documentation, the return value's "list ordering is not specified", and so `get(0)` does not have to return something in the foreground.

Comment: @CommonsWare I tested it by opening multiple applications. But It always gave me the correct package name? Is there any case where it doesn't return the correct one?

Comment: "Is there any case where it doesn't return the correct one?" -- there are thousands of Android devices, made by hundreds of device manufacturers. Those devices are running hundreds of firmware implementations, including ROM mods, across a range of Android versions. And that's just today, let alone what may come about in the future. So, you should not rely upon it, as any of those environments can change the results. And, given Google's other moves for locking down knowledge of what is in the foreground, if this *is* reliable, it's a privacy flaw that needs to get fixed.